# perl code for creating incremental arrays in for loop

Tags: perl

I want to create arrays using for loop when it satisfy the particular condition. Such that  it must create  arrays  say @a1 @a2 @a3 @a4 ... and so on . i have tried the method given below. But, i am not able to do so. Can you plz help

```
   #/bin/usr/perl -w
   use strict;
   my $i; 
   my $m=0;
           for ($i=0 ; $i<10 ; $i++ ) {
                       $a$m[$i]=$i;
                }
  $m++;
  print @a1;
  print @a2;
```

i have tried this way of creating arrays but it is not doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2d array.

```
#!/bin/usr/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my @a;
my $n = 0;
for my $m (0..1) {
   for my $i (0..9) {
      $a[$m][$i] = $n++;
   }
}

print(Dumper(\@a));
```

[Why it's stupid to use a variable as a variable name](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: It would help if you explained the interpretation of the question that you were answering. And *three-space* indents?

Comment: @Borodin, He wants to put stuff in numbered arrays. // Yeah, two is not enough.